# Tokenize QueryStringQuery string using ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elastic 1.7 (and java api).  Is there a good way to use Elastic to tokenize the querystringquery-style string:

```
automobile or car and (telsa or "name is missing" or "aston martin")
```

into the tokens:

```
"automobile", "car", "tesla", "name is missing", "aston martin"
```

It seems like I could use a pattern tokenizer but that pattern gets tricky in a hurry.  Is a better way?

Comment: what is your use case?this seems difficult, it would be good to know what exactly you are trying to achieve so that we might be able to give some alternate solution.

Comment: My use case if very similar to my description.  I need the token parts of a boolean phrase (I pass them to a different web service) and since I am already using Elastic, which I assume has a tokenizer for querystring queries, it thought this might be possible vs writing my own parser.

Answer (score 0):

I used bunch of [pattern replace character filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) for this,

This is my setup

```
"analysis": {
    "char_filter": {
        "space_pattern": {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": "\\s+",
            "replacement": " "
        },
        "replace_space_comma": {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": " ",
            "replacement": "-"
        },
        "replace_and_or_with_hyphen": {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": "(?i)-or-|-and-",
            "replacement": " "
        },
        "remove_brackets": {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": "[()]",
            "replacement": ""
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "token_analyzer": {
            "char_filter": ["html_strip",
                "remove_brackets",
                "space_pattern",
                "replace_space_comma",
                "replace_and_or_with_hyphen"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
    }

}
```

1)`html_strip` is optional (only if you want)

2) Then I am removing brackets `(` and `)` with `remove_brackets`

3) Then I am reducing continuous multiple spaces into one with `space_pattern`

4) After that I am replacing every space with comma with `replace_space_comma`, this is important because then I can use comma to remove `and` AND `or`, you could use any other symbol if you like

5) Final step is removing `and` AND `or`, `(?i)` is case insensitive flag

I am using [whitespace tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html) to divide the text into tokens, I am also using lowercase filter (you could remove this if you want)

so string `automobile or car and (telsa or name is missing or aston martin)` is getting tokenized into

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "automobile",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "car",
         "start_offset": 14,
         "end_offset": 17,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "telsa",
         "start_offset": 23,
         "end_offset": 28,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "name-is-missing",
         "start_offset": 32,
         "end_offset": 47,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 4
      },
      {
         "token": "aston-martin",
         "start_offset": 51,
         "end_offset": 64,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 5
      }
   ]
}
```

This is not perfect, you would have to replace hyphen with space after getting tokens to get desired output

I hope this helps!